# GC_FOR_ALLOC After Layout Inflate

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I am having a lot of GC_FOR_ALLOC fired when inflating the layout.

I have included the onCreate from my Splash.java and also the layout that is inflated.

I have used "Log.i" on every line to see at what point where the GC_FOR_ALLOC is fired and it happens when inflating. If i comment it out it stops!

Any ideas on how to stop them?

### Java Class

```
static LayoutInflater inflater;
public @Override void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);Crashlytics.start(this);

    //inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View splashView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_splash,null); 
    splashView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in)); 
setContentView(splashView);
}
```

### Layout File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription" > 

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:text="@string/app_eula"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" /> 

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" /> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/splash_logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" > 

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/error_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_error" /> 

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" > 

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error_line_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LINE 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="16sp" /> 

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error_line_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="LINE 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="12sp" /> 
        </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/splash_logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" > 

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" /> 
    </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```